# How to maximize and minimize $x^2$ on $[0, 1]$.

Tags: calculus

Have the $f(x)=x^2$ maximize and minimize $f$ over $[0,1]$. What happens in terms of the maximum and minimum of $f$ if it is changed to $[0, 1)$?

Comment: Hi @Martin! $$\color{red}{\Large\text{Welcome to MSE!}}$$ Please share your thoughts so far in future :)

Answer (score 1):

1. For $x\in\left[0,1\right]$, we have $f\left(x\right)_{min}=f\left(0\right)=0,f\left(x\right)_{max}=f\left(1\right)=1$. For $f^{'}\left(x\right)=2x>0$ in the domain $\left[0,1\right]$.
2. For $x\in\left[0,1\right)$, $f\left(x\right)$ have the minimum but do not have a maximum, which minimum is $f\left(0\right)=0$.

   While in calculus by using limit we get $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 1}{f\left(x\right)=1}$, but $f\left(x\right)$ can not achieve the value $1$, just can tend to it.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)$ is increasing in the domain $[0,1]$(How? Think). So minimum occurs at $0$ and maximum occurs at $1$.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the critical points i.e. $f'(x)=0$ and find the value of $f$ at those points in your interval
2. find the value of $f$ at the end points, namely, $x=0,1$
3. compare these values to determine the max and min.